# Javascript Decorators: How to store function with this scope?

Tags: javascript, decorator, babeljs, es6-class

I would like to create a decorator to store a function with this scope in an array for every instance created of a class
I can't find the right words to explain so here let's say i have the following code:

```
class Foo
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.MyValue = "Foo";
    }

    @StoreFunction()
    TestA()
    {
        console.log("Foo MyValue:", this.MyValue);
    }
}
class Bar extends Foo
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.MyValue = "Bar";
    }

    @StoreFunction()
    TestB()
    {
        console.log("Bar MyValue:", this.MyValue);
    }
}

function StoreFunction()
{
    return function(target, key, descriptor)
    {
        // How would i go about saving the function there so i can call it later??
        return descriptor;
    }
}
```

I know that decorators are not processed during class instantiation. So i tried doing the following in **StoreFunction**.

```
var StoredFunctions = [];

function StoreFunction()
{
    return function(target, key, descriptor)
    {
        if(target._StoredFunctions)
        {
            target._StoredFunctions = [];
        }
        // Save the function's name
        target._StoredFunctions.push(key);

        return descriptor;
    }
}
```

Then binding them in the constructor.

```
class Foo
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.MyValue = "Foo";
        this.BindFunctions()
    }

    BindFunctions()
    {
        if(this._StoredFunctions)
        {
            this._StoredFunctions.forEach( method => {
                StoredFunctions.push(this[method].bind(this));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But again the this._StoredFunctions does not store the StoredFunctions properly since they are static. I am not quite sure how to make it work properly.

Please let me know if the question is not clear i am having a hard time explaining the issue.

Comment: What is the end result you want to achieve? I'm particularly confused by the phrase "expose the function," as methods are not hidden on objects, so they don't need to be exposed.

Comment: When you say "expose the function" are you trying to put them in a globally accessible array "to be used for later"? Why not just use the object and its method "later"?

Comment: I know they are not hidden objects. I would like to put them into an array and bind them to keyboard events or any other events i trigger.
So lets say i create a function with this decorator then i can create an instance of this class and call all these functions for every instance created.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert an automatic subclass that can handle doing the necessary work of "exposing" (or otherwise doing things with) the marked functions, see comments:

```
// `exposable` sets the class up for `exposed` on methods
function exposable() {
    return function decorator(target, name) {
        // Create our subclass with the same name
        const o = {[name]: class extends target {
            constructor(...args) {
                super(...args);
                // "Expose" the bound methods
                this.exposed = {};
                Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target.prototype).forEach(name => {
                    const method = target.prototype[name];
                    if (method.exposed) {
                        this.exposed[name] = method.bind(this);
                    }
                });
            }
        }};
        return o[name];
    };
}

// `expose` marks a method to be exposed in the constructor
function exposed(state) {
    return function decorator(target, name, config) {
        config.value.exposed = true;
        return config;
    };
}

// Example
@exposable()
class Foo {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @exposed()
    testA() {
        console.log("testA says " + this.name);
    }

    testB() {
        console.log("testB says " + this.name);
    }
}

const f = new Foo("Fred");
f.exposed.testA(); // Says "testA says Fred" because it's bound
```

---

You've said we can rely on having a common base class (`Foo`). If so, we can move the logic into `Foo` itself:

```
// `expose` marks a method to be exposed in the constructor
function exposed(state) {
    return function decorator(target, name, config) {
        config.value.exposed = true;
        return config;
    };
}

// Example
class Foo {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.exposed = Object.create(null);
        let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
        while (proto && proto !== Object.prototype) {
            Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto).forEach(name => {
                if (!this.exposed[name]) {
                    const method = this[name];
                    if (typeof method === "function" && method.exposed) {
                        // Expose it
                        this.exposed[name] = method.bind(this);
                    }
                }
            });
            proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
        }
    }

    @exposed()
    testA() {
        console.log("testA says " + this.name);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {

    @exposed()
    testB() {
        console.log("testB says " + this.name);
    }
}

const f = new Foo("Fred");
f.exposed.testA(); // Says "testA says Fred" because it's bound
const b = new Bar("Barney");
b.exposed.testA(); // Says "testA says Barney" because it's bound
b.exposed.testB(); // Says "testB says Barney" because it's bound
```

Comment: Is there a way to leave the @exposable() decorator from the class so i only have to put the decorator on the function?

Comment: @Azarus: I can't immediately think of one unless you decorate `constructor` instead, which is basically the same thing. (Unless, of course, you're happy to require coding a "setup" call in every constructor manually.)

Comment: Hmm and if i create a function in the parent class that itartes over every class method and looks if the function has .exposed property? Then bind the functions accordingly?

Comment: Sure, if they're all going to have a superclasss, the superclass constructor could do it. That would eliminate most of the complexity above.

Comment: So then the @exposed only has to bind one variable to the function and not bind the actual function to any array. So on intialization i get the list of funcitons in every instance

Comment: @Azarus: Yes (instance or its prototype or its prototype's prototype, etc.). `Foo` didn't have a superclass in your example, so I didn't realize they'd all have one.

Comment: Yeah Foo was the superclass and the child was Bar

Comment: @Azarus: I just didn't realize everything would have to derive from `Foo`. I've added an example of relying on subclassing `Foo`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I really don't know why i got stuck on this :)

Answer (score 0):

T.J. Crowder provided a correct answer, i am providing a clean and readable solution that i came up with based on T.J. Crowder.

```
var StoredFunctions = {};
class Foo
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.MyValue = "Foo";
        this.SetupStore();
    }

    SetupStore()
    {
        let Methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(this));
        for(let Method of Methods)
        {
            if(typeof(this[Method]) == "function" && this[Method]._StoredFunction)
            {
                StoredFunctions[Method] = this[Method].bind(this);
            }

        }
    }

    @StoreFunction()
    TestA()
    {
        console.log("Foo MyValue:", this.MyValue);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.MyValue = "Bar";
    }

    @StoreFunction()
    TestB()
    {
        console.log("Bar MyValue:", this.MyValue);
    }
}



function StoreFunction(StoreInfo)
{
    return function(target, key, descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.value._StoredFunction = true; // Mark the function to be stored on initialization
        return descriptor;
    }
}
```